# Prove that for all $x \in\mathbb{R}, 1 + 99\sin^2(x) \ge 10\sin(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Prove that for all $x \in\mathbb{R}, 1 + 99\sin^2(x) \ge 10\sin(2x)$

First, i did move everything to left,

$$1 + 99\sin^2(x)-10\sin(2x) \ge 0$$

so for prove this, i have to prove $1 + 99\sin^2(x)-10\sin(2x)$ is $0$ or positive number.

that mean prove $1 + 99\sin^2(x)-10\sin(2x)$ is not a negative number.

if I can make $1 + 99\sin^2(x)-10\sin(2x)$ to $n^2$, that will be prove(because $x \in\mathbb{R}$, and all (Real Number)$^2$ is positive number)

but I can't find any breakthrough point for that, could i can get some hint?

i tried that, but that's end and I can't find any next step.

$$1 + 99(\sin(x)\sin(x))-10\sin(2x) \ge 0$$

$$1 + 99\sin^2(x)+(-10)(2\sin(x)\cos(x)) \ge 0$$

$$1 + 99(\sin(x)\sin(x))+(-10)(2\sin(x)\cos(x)) \ge 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simpler that it seems. Express everything as

functions of $tanx$. Then we get

$1+99(1-cos^{2}(x))\geq\,10\dfrac{2tanx}{1+tan^{2}(x)}$ which  is equivalent to:

$100-\dfrac{99}{1+tan^{2}(x)}\geq\,20\dfrac{tanx}{1+tan^{2}(x)}$ which

is equivalent to :$100+100tan^{2}(x)-99\geq\,20tanx$

i.e.$\,\,\,(1-10tanx)^{2}\geq\,0$ which is clearly true!!

Answer (score 5):

Turn $1$ into $sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)$ seems useful.

Turn $sin(2x)$ into $2sin(x)cos(x)$ also seems useful.

Then you can turn the expression $1 + 99\sin^2(x)-10\sin(2x)$ into a square.

Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$, it follows that the inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{101}{2}\geq 10\sin(2x)+\frac{99}{2}\cos(2x).$$
Now notice that by the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality),
$$\frac{101}{2}\cdot 1=\sqrt{10^2+\left(\frac{99}{2}\right)^2}\cdot\sqrt{\sin^2(2x)+\cos^2(2x)}\geq 10\sin(2x)+\frac{99}{2}\cos(2x)$$
and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use AM-GM:
$$\cos^2x+100\sin^2x\ge 2\sqrt{100\cos^2x\sin^2x}=20|\sin x \cos x| \ge 10\sin2x$$